# Sublime Text3 Import error: cannot import name Elasticsearch

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, sublimetext3

***>>import elasticsearch*** 
is working on terminal but not working when run with the sublime-Text3.

when i'am importing elasticsearch on sublime it shows : **ImportError: cannot import name Elasticsearch**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime bundles it's own version of Python and related core libraries that are separate and distinct from any that might be defined by the system python.

Since the two environments are distinct, it can't see anything that you haven't specifically told it to. In this case that would mean that whatever package you're developing would need to include that library as well.